# Identify columns having mix of Dr and Cr values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

I have an Excel file where columns E to BB have amount values, the cells of which are formatted using Custom Format as either ""0.00" Cr" or ""0.00" Dr"

I want to check whether any given column has all values as Dr or all values as Cr, or whether the column conatins mix of Dr and Cr values.

Without using an individual helper column for each of the columns E to BB, is there a quick way to check this? I am okay to use a single helper column, if it helps but wish to avoid one helper column for each column. A macro is also ok, though I prefer solution without macro.

For example,
cell E4 displays the value as 24279.97 in the formula bar, but the actual cell displays the value as 24279.97 Dr, and the custom format is ""0.00" Dr"

[image]

[image]

Comment: You will need a macro for this. See https://superuser.com/questions/1399354/excel-2013-detect-cell-currency-format

Comment: What are the custom format rules? You may use the same logic to get to your answer.

Comment: What version of Excel do you use?

Comment: What form do you want the results to be in? (All columns? selected column? where?)

Do you want to compare cell formats or what's displayed in them? (A cell can be formatted but not containing a number.)

Comment: Excel version is 2016. The results can be in any form, it can be simply the column names which contain a mix of both Dr and Cr amounts. I want to identify whether any column contains both Dr and Cr number formats. @MGonet

Comment: Based on the fact that you have 2 formats it looks like you are going through each cell and making the selection of the DR/CR format. To continue down this path, as suggested, you'll need a macro. As alluded to by @P.b if you were to reframe your spreadsheet adding in logic that determines what is a DR/CR (using positive and negative numbers for example), then formulas can get to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the 2016 version, the UDF function written in VBA will probably work best.
As I've written before, you need to distinguish between cases where a cell is formatted but doesn't use that format because it's empty or doesn't contain a number. So when you compare the format codes, you can get a different result than when you compare what the cells display.
To compare format codes, you can use, for example, the following function:

```
  Function CompNFs(x As Range) As String
       ' compares NumberFomats in columns of an x Range
       Dim c As Range, cc As Range, cel As Range
       Dim CountCR As Long, CountDr As Long
       For Each c In x.Rows(1).Cells
          CountDr = 0: CountCR = 0
          Set cc = Intersect(c.EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
          For Each cel In cc
             If InStr(cel.NumberFormat, "Dr") > 0 Then
                CountDr = CountDr + 1
             ElseIf InStr(cel.NumberFormat, "Cr") > 0 Then
                CountCR = CountCR + 1
             End If
          Next cel
          If CountDr * CountCR > 0 Then CompNFs = CompNFs & _
             Split(c.EntireColumn.Address(0, 0), ":")(0) & ", "
       Next c
       If Len(CompNFs) > 0 Then
          CompNFs = "Columns with mixed formats: " & Left(CompNFs, Len(CompNFs) - 2)
       Else
          CompNFs = "No mixed formats."
       End If
    End Function
```

The function that compares the displayed texts will look completely similar (the difference is only in the property used):

```
Function CompText(x As Range) As String
       ' compares formatted Output in columns of an x Range
       Dim c As Range, cc As Range, cel As Range
       Dim CountCR As Long, CountDr As Long
       For Each c In x.Rows(1).Cells
          CountDr = 0: CountCR = 0
          Set cc = Intersect(c.EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
          For Each cel In cc
             If InStr(cel.Text, "Dr") > 0 Then
                CountDr = CountDr + 1
             ElseIf InStr(cel.Text, "Cr") > 0 Then
                CountCR = CountCR + 1
             End If
          Next cel
          If CountDr * CountCR > 0 Then CompText = CompText & _
             Split(c.EntireColumn.Address(0, 0), ":")(0) & ", "
       Next c
       If Len(CompText) > 0 Then
          CompText = "Columns with mixed output: " & Left(CompText, Len(CompText) - 2)
       Else
          CompText = "No mixed ouput."
       End If
    End Function
```

When the function is called in the worksheet you specify the single row range of cells. In response, the function will return a list of columns where both codes are used. All used cells in the specified columns are checked.

The screenshot is from Polish version of Excel.
[image: NumberFormat_symbols]